# Email cannot be sent: make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly

Tags: workflow, error, email

I made a three-state workflow in my issue list. But when I added a new item and assigned a user, a workflow is in progress the error appeared.

> the email cannot be sent. make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly

What should I write in **outbound SMTP server** in configure outgoing email settings? 
What should i do?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is step you need to configure the Outbound SMTP Server with powershell

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$SMTPSvr = 'mail.contoso.com'
$FromAddr = 'noreply@contoso.com'
$ReplyAddr = 'noreply@contoso.com'
$Charset = 65001

$CAWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Where { $_.IsAdministrationWebApplication }
$CAWebApp.UpdateMailSettings($SMTPSvr, $FromAddr, $ReplyAddr, $Charset)
```

More info:
http://mikefrobbins.com/2011/08/04/configure-sharepoint-2010-outgoing-email-settings-with-powershell/

Comment: Thank you.
My problem is solved.

Comment: is that my answer help you to resolve your issue? if yes, please mark answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your helping Supermode. But I solved my problem by writing  SPServerName.Domain in outbound SMTP server. Thank you anyway.